# Angular reactive form [disabled] attribute doesn't work for text field based on validity of another text field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

below is the code snippet for angular reactive form field. The button stays disable until I valid input in mobile field but the same doesn't work for text field. I want second input text field to be disabled until I enter a valid input to mobile field.

```
 <div id="mobile_verification">
        <input class="form-control" id="mobile" formControlName="mobile" placeholder="Mobile no." maxlength="10">
        <input class="form-control" id="otp" [disabled]= "!contactForm.controls['mobile'].valid" formControlName="otp" placeholder="OTP" maxlength="6">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.controls['otp'].valid" class="btn btn-success">Verify</button>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.controls['mobile'].valid" class="btn btn-success">Resend</button>
 </div>
```

Is there any another way for text field or am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `[disabled]` doesn't work with reactive forms on form controls, you need to "manually" disable/enable

Comment: [readonly] would work if it's an option for you

Comment: @AJT_82  I don't think this question is duplicate as I need to decide the enable/disable based on validity of some other text field and not . If I'm wrong please explain. 
In 2nd comment you mentioned **[disabled] doesn't work with reactive forms on form controls**, but it works for button, isn't it form control?

Vega It's not read only field :-)

Comment: @user2604307 Your button does not a have an `formControlName` notation does it? So no, buttons are not a form controls :)

Comment: And as for being a duplicate. It pretty much is. You need to track the value of the field, and then disable/enable the other field accordingly.

Comment: Ok, make sense @AJT_82. So does that mean in angular reactive form doesn't allow us this functionality, and we need to find a hacky alternative? If so, can you please suggest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` attribute does not work on form controls in reactive forms. You need to "manually" enable and disable the form field. This could be done in a couple of ways that I can think of. Use `valueChanges` on `mobile` field and then disable/enable the `otp` field based on the validity of `mobile` field.

I like to listen to some change event, where `(keyup)` would perhaps be most suitable here. You could call a method or use the content of method in template. I like to keep the template clean tho and handle logic in component. So you could set a event for the `mobile` field:

```html
<input formControlName="mobile" (keyup)="checkValidity()"/>
```

and then the corresponding method:

```ts
checkValidity() {
   this.myForm.get('mobile').valid ? 
   this.myForm.get('otp').enable() : this.myForm.get('otp').disable();
}
```

Also if this is an empty form initially, you would want to set the `otp` field as disabled initially:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  mobile: ['', [....]],
  otp: [{value:'' disabled:true}]
});
```

**DEMO**: http://plnkr.co/edit/SbN3lJNjvXrE26UyVl6j?p=preview

Comment: perfect mate! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Great. glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just say form.invalid like below

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">Verify</button>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">Resend</button>
```

which will validate entire form to be valid.

for individual form field, they have also valid and invalid field

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!opt.valid" class="btn btn-success">Verify</button>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!opt.valid" class="btn btn-success">Resend</button>
```

For the input fields if the directly not working you can put them in a div and hide them

```
<span *ngIf="opt.invalid && (opt.dirty || opt.touched)" class="text-danger align-middle">
               <input ...></input>
</span>
```

Comment: button works for me, my concern here is for text field.

Comment: put it inside a div/span and hide it

Comment: i validate it in below way it might help  -- <span *ngIf="username.invalid && (username.dirty || username.touched)" class="text-danger align-middle">
                <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Username is required
              </span>