# Disable a field in angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

In my angular 6 application, i am making a reactive form which has,

**Html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <h2>Click the add button below</h2>
    <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>
    <div formArrayName="credentials" >
      <div *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials').controls; let i = index" 
          [formGroupName]="i" style="display: flex">
          <select formControlName="action">
             <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option.key}}">
               {{option.value}} 
             </option>
          </select>
          <input placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
<div *ngIf="creds.value.action=='set' ||
      creds.value.action=='go'">
                   <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here i have used

`<div *ngIf="creds.value.action=='set' || creds.value.action=='go'">
<input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
 </div>`

which will display the field `label` if the condition is true or else it will not be displayed.

But i need to only disable that field and should not remove it completely..

For which i have tried,

`<input [disabled]="creds.value.action != 'set' ||
      creds.value.action != 'go' " placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">`

But it doesn't works.

**Stackblitz with *ngIf** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-25y1ix

**Stackblitz with disabled** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-laftgu

Kindly help me how to disable the `label` field if the selected `action` (first dropdown) value is `wait`..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular reactive form \[disabled\] attribute doesn't work for text field based on validity of another text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945025/angular-reactive-form-disabled-attribute-doesnt-work-for-text-field-based-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a CSS class:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events:none;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

Add a method to your Component:

```
getValueByIndex(index) {
  const actionValue = ( < FormArray > this.form.get('credentials')).at(index).value.action;
  return actionValue !== 'set' && actionValue !== 'go';
}
```

Use this method in your template:

```
<input 
    [class.disabled]="getValueByIndex(i)" 
    placeholder="Label" 
    formControlName="label">
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-form-array?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

---

### UPDATE:

Alternatively, you can do the following:

Make the `label` field disabled by default:

```
addCreds() {
  const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
  creds.push(this.fb.group({
    action: '',
    name: '',
    label: {
      value: '',
      disabled: true
    },
    state: 'na'
  }));
}
```

And then listen to the `(ngModelChange)` event on the form to update the state of the label field:

```
<select 
  formControlName="action"
  (ngModelChange)="($event === 'set' || $event === 'go') ? creds.controls.label.enable() : creds.controls.label.disable()">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let option of data" 
    [value]="option.key">
    {{option.value}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-smok31?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for this approach.

---

Thanks to A.Winnen for his comments on the performance implications of using the previous approach.

Comment: What is the solution if i am not changing the dropdown but has some default value?? Say in action i am going to have default value as ```set``` then the respective ```label``` field needs to get enabled.. Because this solution works only in ```ngModelChange``` but i need result for both change as well as if there was a default value patched to the ```action```..

Answer (score 0):

In Reactive Form you cannot use the disabled directive. Instead, you'll need to disable the formControl the 'reactive way' by calling enable() or disable() function.

```js
addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    const newGroup = this.fb.group({
      action: '',
      name: '',
      label: ''
    });
    newGroup.controls.action.valueChanges.subscribe((currentAction) => {
      if (typeof currentAction === "string" && currentAction.toLowerCase() === 'wait') {
        newGroup.controls.label.disable();
      } else {
        newGroup.controls.label.enable();
      }
    });
    creds.push(newGroup);
  }
```

I modified your stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-ymysw4